Smallest screen resolution supported / very narrow display
Per the title really, we're looking at an application where we use a very narrow "bar" type display but the vertical resolution would be under 100 pixels, is there any info on how low you can go with the standard Raspbian or other well-supported OS options?
Would the interface make any difference (EG would HDMI cause problems but direct RGB would be OK)?
